Magnific popup printing tags in sprint
I am using Magnific Popup for an image gallery. However, the counter is displaying the HTML tags as plain text on the frontend.
Here is my configuration:
$(".open-popup").magnificPopup({
    type: "image",
    fixedContentPos: true,
    gallery: {
        enabled: true,
        tCounter: '<span class="mfp-counter">%curr% of %total%</span>',
    },
});

With the above configuration, the counter is showing the  tag as plain text instead of rendering it properly.
Here is the CodePen link for reference: https://codepen.io/swaranan/pen/PwYwoXK


You need to set the allowHTMLInTemplate option to true.

allowHTMLInTemplate
false
Available since 1.2.0. Allows HTML content in the source template (such as text under image). If you enable this - make sure your HTML attributes are sanitized if they can be created by a non-admin user.


Perfect. Thank you.
